# TweenEngine library vs libGDX Interpolation class

Tags: libgdx

I'm developing a game based on the libGDX framework in eclipse that will have smoothly movements between my entities, so for that, I have used [TweenEngine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2011/04/java-universal-tween-engine/) (and it is working nice), but recently I found that libGDX have its own [class for interpolations](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Interpolation.html).

I know both are for tweening (or for nice and smoothly animations), and I just want to know if there are technical difference or limitations between this 2 options basically because if both are the same, I would opt for the second one since it is already inside libGDX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one side there's generally better to use included tools because of integration and final application size (not saying of setting up the environment or exporting project problems).

On the other hand please notice that Libgdx [Interpolation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Interpolation.html) starts to be useful only when you are using it with [Scene2D actions](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d). And here is the problem in my opinion because you must implement stage and actors mechanisms - which is good idea by itelf but can be almost impossible if you have created almost whole application without it.

Then I would recommend you:

- choose Scene2D actions + Interpolation easing **if you are able to implement Scene2D in your project and the easing actions are only reason you want to use Tween Engine**
- choose Universal Tween Engine **if you want to stay independent of new machanisms and use Sprites etc in traditional way**

Comment: I though the Interpolation class was a little more flexible ): . I'll keep using Tween Engine then, since I am in the second case you mention, thanks.